Measure for the size of ordinal intervals
TLDR:

Does the Veblen hierarchy make bigger and bigger jumps?

Motivation:
I am looking for a way to measure the width of an interval of ordinals. The first clue is its cardinality, but if two intervals have the same cardinality, the measure should coincide with our notion that e.g. $[0, \omega^2)$ is wider than $[\omega^3, \omega^3+\omega)$.
I tried a definition that used ordinal addition but that resulted in having $[0, \omega^2)$ the same width as $[\omega, \omega^2)$, which I find undesireable.
Instead lets define the following:

Let $I_1 = [\alpha_1, \beta_1)$ and $I_2$ = $[\alpha_2, \beta_2)$ be ordinal intervals.
Call $I_1$ embeddable into $I_2$ iff there is an injection $f$ with:

$ f(\alpha_1) = \alpha_2 $
$a$ is a successor iff $f(a)$ is a successor
$f(a+1) = f(a)+1$

Call $I_2$ wider as $I_1$ iff $I_1$ is embeddable into some subinterval of $I_2$, but $I_2$ is not embeddable into some subinterval of $I_1$ (subintervals need not to be proper).

I suspect that some intervals will be incomparable, but hopefully not the ones I care about for the following questions (all quantifiers are countable):

Is $[\varepsilon_0, \varepsilon_1)$ wider than $[0, \varepsilon_0)$?
Is $[\varepsilon_\alpha, \varepsilon_{\alpha+1})$ wider than $[\varepsilon_\beta, \varepsilon_{\beta+1})$ for $\beta > \alpha$?
Is $[\varphi_{\gamma}(\beta), \varphi_{\gamma}(\beta+1))$ wider than $[\varphi_{\gamma}(\alpha), \varphi_{\gamma}(\alpha+1))$ for $\beta > \alpha$?
Is $[\varphi_{\delta}(0), \varphi_{\delta}(1))$ wider than $[\varphi_{\gamma}(\alpha), \varphi_{\gamma}(\alpha+1))$ for $\delta > \gamma$ and any $\alpha$?


You definition of measure has that $[\omega,\omega^2)$ and $[0,\omega^2)$ still have the same size. In fact, let $f$ be the injection which sends $\alpha\mapsto \omega+\alpha$.

@GiorgioGenovesi, that is unfortunate. If you have an idea how to fix the definition, go ahead. Otherwise I'll leave it as is.

I believe, that although it has this undesirable property, you can in fact show the gaps do get larger. This is because for example $\epsilon_1>\epsilon_0+\epsilon_0$. Also ordinals are meant to capture order types. So measuring intervals by their order type is quite natural.
